# Issues with adding a link via mouse click to two nodes in force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create an interactive graph. For this I would like to click on two nodes and create a link (later on I would like to remove one if it exists).

I followed Mike Bostock's example:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795

I added this function:

```
function changeLink() { 

  if (nodeobjList.length < 1) {
    nodeobjList.push(nodeobj)
  } else if (nodeobjList.length == 1) {
    nodeobjList.push(nodeobj)

    firstnode = nodeobjList[0]
    secondnode = nodeobjList[1]

    graphLinks.push({source: firstnode.id, target: secondnode.id, value: 1 });
    console.log(graphLinks)

    // Apply the general update pattern to the links.
    link = link.data(graphLinks, function(d) { return firstnode.id + "-" + secondnode.id; });
    link.exit().remove();
    link = link.enter().append("line").merge(link);

 // Update and restart the simulation.
 simulation.nodes(nodes);
 simulation.force("link").links(link);
 simulation.alpha(1).restart();

    }
}
```

This produces an error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'vx' on string 'MotherPlutarch'"
```

So I replaced the id with the object as in:

```
graphLinks.push({source: firstnode, target: secondnode, value: 1 });
```

This time the graph moves with all of its points into the upper left corner.
The error is:

```
Error: <line> attribute x1: Expected length, "NaN".
```

I could get the x,y coordinates for the beginning and end of the line via mouse position, or by filtering nodes by id. But since the nodes are all moving to the upper left corner I suspect something more complex is wrong or missing.

Does anybody know what is going on?
Many thanks in advance,
Markus

For more details I am adding the complete html file here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var defs = svg.append('defs');
defs.append("pattern")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 1)
    .attr("height", 1)
    .attr("id", "test")
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", 'https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/open_graph/github-octocat.png')
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 60)
    .attr("x", -30)
    .attr("y", -10);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var node;
var link;
var graphNodes;
var graphLinks;
var nodeobjList = [];
var nodeobj;

d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

 // build the arrow.
  svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
        .data(["end"])                    // Different link/path types can be defined here
        .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
        .attr("id", String)
        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 13)
        .attr("refY", 0)
        .attr("markerWidth", 9)
        .attr("markerHeight", 9)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .attr("xoverflow",'visible')
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5")
        .attr('fill', '#999')
        .style('stroke','none');

  link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

  graphLinks = graph.links
  graphNodes = graph.nodes

  node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 20)
      .on("click", function(d){
        d3.select(this).attr("fill", "url(#test)")
      })
      .on("dblclick", function(d){
         nodeobj = d
         changeLink();
      })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended))

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

function changeLink() { 

    if (nodeobjList.length < 1) {
        nodeobjList.push(nodeobj)
    } else if (nodeobjList.length == 1) {
        nodeobjList.push(nodeobj)

        firstnode = nodeobjList[0]
        secondnode = nodeobjList[1]

        graphLinks.push({source: firstnode, target: secondnode, value: 1 });

    console.log(graphLinks)

        // Apply the general update pattern to the links.
        link = link.data(graphLinks, function(d) { return firstnode + "-" + secondnode; });
        link.exit().remove();
        link = link.enter().append("line").merge(link);

        // Update and restart the simulation.
        simulation.nodes(nodes);
        simulation.force("link").links(link);
        simulation.alpha(1).restart();

    }
}
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of things wrong here

1. Referencing the wrong arrays when updating the simulation

   simulation.nodes(nodes);
   simulation.force("link").links(link);

Both nodes and link should be referencing your graphNodes and graphLinks arrays

2. You should clear the nodeobjList array after creating your new link, eg

   nodeobjList = []

For example, your updated code could look like this, which refers more to Bostock's example you cited:

```
function changeLink() { 

    if (nodeobjList.length < 1) {
        nodeobjList.push(nodeobj)
    } else if (nodeobjList.length == 1) {
        nodeobjList.push(nodeobj)
        firstnode = nodeobjList[0].id
        secondnode = nodeobjList[1].id

        graphLinks.push({source: firstnode, target: secondnode, value: 1 });

        nodeobjList = []
        restart();

    }
}


 function restart() {
        link = link.data(graphLinks, function(d) { return firstnode + "-" + secondnode; });
        link.exit().remove();
        link = link.enter().append("line").merge(link);

        // Update and restart the simulation.
        simulation.force("link").links(graphLinks);
        simulation.alpha(1).restart();
 }
```